# Invalidate Firestore cache upon deserialization error

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently running a development instance of the database - one whose structure/schema is also being worked upon. As a result, sometimes the Android client crashes because of a RuntimeException `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object.` like if the builtin converter factory was expecting a String but received an int etc.

The error is helpful since it pinpoints the source of error. However, the problem lies when I fix the data on the Firestore backend it doesn't quite reflect in the Android client right away. The app tries to populate the RecyclerView using the cached data (the invalid data) and so it crashes upon start each time until I completely reset the app.

Is there a way to handle this error by invalidating the cache or looking for updated data whenever it occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your production code is going to have to be resilient to changes that could happen in Firestore.  That's probably not going to change, so you should only ship changes that your confident about handling in the app.

During testing, if you're making changes that break your app, simply uninstall and reinstall the app to clear the cache.

Comment: The original question is basically asking about that good way to make the production code resilient.